# Increment strings to get the next month and year

Tags: php, date, time

I have 2 variables that reference a month number and a year number:

```
$month = $_REQUEST['month'];
$month1 = sprintf("%02s", $month);;

$year1 = $_REQUEST['year'];
$date1 = $month1.'/01/'.$year1;
```

This is all working as expected. I now need to get similar variables for the next month. So in plain English this would be the equivalent of:

```
$month2 = $month1 + 1; // e.g. if $month1 = 12, $month2 = 01 and $year2 = $year1 + 1
```

I don't believe `$date1` is in the required date format so I'm not sure if I can use any date functions, or if it's simpler to use math to increment the numbers?

Comment: have you tried combination of `date` and `strtotime` ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DateTime`

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', sprintf('%d/01/%d',
        $_REQUEST['month'], $_REQUEST['year']));

$interval = new DateInterval('P1M'); // 1 month

echo $dt->add($interval)->format('m/d/Y');
```

Comment: @zzlalani Oh please, PHP 5.3.0 was released on 30th June, 2009. I shouldn't have to keep saying this

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) (which will work on PHP >= 5.2.0):

```php
$month = $_REQUEST['month'];
$year  = $_REQUEST['year'];
$date  = new DateTime("$year-$month-1");
$date->modify('+1 month');
echo "Next month is: ", $date->format('Y-m');
```

<kbd>**[`demo`](http://3v4l.org/DUQhW)**</kbd>